# Writing a SQL query to join a local data frame and a table in a connected postgreSQL database in R

Tags: r, postgresql, join

Former SAS user trying to learn R on the job..

Friends.... Is there really no way to create a data frame by writing a SQL query that joins a local data frame (localtable1) and a table in a connected postgreSQL database (database.table1) in R? I have been Googling for hours and still can't find the answer. It's SO EASY ON SAS!

What I am trying to do:

```
(create table created as) select * from localtable1 a inner join database.table1 b on a.id = b.id and a.study_id = b.study_id
```

Am I missing something? I have already installed dplyr, DBI, and sqldf trying to figure this out.

Thanks friends!

Comment: I think you'll have to write your data frame to the database and perform the join operation with both tables there, either with {dbplyr} or {DBI}. Our internal package has a special function to do just this.

Comment: create a string of the id values and put them in a where clause  "where id in (12, 56, ...)"  Put that in the query sent to the data base and bring back the matching items.  Then merge locally.

Comment: @DavidRanzolin The postgresql database is read only so I can't write things into it...

Comment: @HarlanNelson what if I want to join the tables on two variables (as the code above, a.id=b.id AND a.study_id = b.study_id)

Comment: @HarlanNelson That was what we originally tried, but Oracle at least has a 1000 WHERE...IN limit.